# Only checking if a certain property of a document has changed in cloud functions

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I want to be able to only execute the if statement, if the *done* (bool) property on the todo document changes, and not worry about the rest of the document.

As the current issue that if a todo name is changed, this function gets called even though the done property has not changed.

```
exports.watchTodos = functions.firestore.document('users/{uid}/todos/{docId}')
    .onUpdate((snap, context) => {

        const data = snap.after.data();
        const isDone = data.done;           

        if (isDone === true) {
              console.log('add points')
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to only trigger a Cloud Function on a specific change to a document, so you will have to detect that in your implementation of the function.

To detect if the `done` field has changed, you can compare its `before` and `after` values with something like this:

```
if (snap.before.data().isDone != snap.after.data().isDone) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems from your question, that you want to trigger the Cloud Function when `isDone` is set to `true`.

Therefore, another possibility would be to create a document in a specific extra collection when you set the value of `isDone` to `true` in your todo doc.

You will trigger a Cloud Function each time a new document is created in this dedicated collection.

In your front end, you would use a batched write to simultaneously write to the two collections (the `todos` subcollection and the "dedicated" collection). You can assign to the document created in the "dedicated" collection the same ID than the user or the todo document. This way, in the onCreate Cloud Function you know which user or todo doc triggered the doc creation (and the CF execution).